# How to print 74 Characters perline using base 64 algorithem in oracle pl/sql when working with clob datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is my code which will do the Image Coversion into base 64 algorithem.But I need 74 Characters per line. Existing base64  algoritehm is giving 64 characters per line.(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode )

```
Image  BLOB;
v_out_cl     CLOB; 
file_len     PLS_INTEGER;
  modulo       PLS_INTEGER;
  pieces       PLS_INTEGER;
  amt          BINARY_INTEGER      := 23808;
  buf          RAW (32767);
  buf_tx       varchar2(32767);
  pos          PLS_INTEGER         := 1;
  filepos      PLS_INTEGER         := 1;
  counter      PLS_INTEGER         := 1;

DBMS_LOB.createtemporary   (v_out_cl, TRUE, dbms_lob.call);
                  file_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength (Image );
                  modulo := MOD (file_len, amt);
                  pieces := TRUNC (file_len / amt);

                  WHILE (counter <= pieces) LOOP
                    DBMS_LOB.READ (Image, amt, filepos, buf);
                    buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2
                       (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (buf));
                    dbms_lob.writeappend
                       (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
                    filepos := counter * amt + 1;
                    counter := counter + 1;
                  END LOOP;

                  IF (modulo <> 0) THEN
                    DBMS_LOB.READ
                      (image , modulo, filepos, buf);
                    buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2
                      (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (buf));
                    dbms_lob.writeappend
                      (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
                  END IF;
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want 74 chars per line ? The standard just says that characters outside the range of the encoding bytes (notably line separating CRLF characters) should be ignored.

Comment: There is a requirement to print encoded image in 76 characters each line.so if we print 74 characters and last 2 characters will be CRLF.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any flags to change the line size of `utl_encode.base64_encode`. You'll probably have to resort to an additional copy pass. I haven't tested the impact on overall performance.

Under linux there is the `base64` command that provides a flag to set the column width. Assuming you have the file 'col-64.b64' with 64 columns per line, the following command will transcode it to 74 cols per line:

```
base64 -d col-64.b64 | base64 -w 74 >col-74.b64
```

**Note**

In principle, there should be no need for a specific line length - The standard just says that characters outside the range of the encoding bytes (notably line separating CRLF characters) should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks Collapsar.  Can we call javaclass from plsql instead of using UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode  to print 74 Characters.My requirement is convert the image into encoded format and each line should be 74 characters.